# Creating shapes based on Touch

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I want to draw different shapes on iphone screen based on touch & want to give a name to it.

Suppose user touch at 4 points on the screen then it will create 4 dots on screen which ultimately create a rectangle.

Then suppose i want to give a name to that shape, i should be able to give a name to it by entering some text in side that shape.

Till now i can able to draw dots on the screen based on touch and based on dot i also able to draw a continuous line on screen.

But i dont understand how can create the shape as visually it is displaying like a particular shape but in reality it is not and how can i enter some text inside these shape.

Comment: your question is not clear. please reformat it. Use Steps 1,2,3... that you want to have and what is the problem you are facing

Answer (score 1):

Get the four points and create a new UIView matching those points. Add it to the main view. If that view is a UILabel, you can readily add text inside it. If a UITextField, then users can use the standard iOS text editing approach of "tap text field, keyboard appears".